# How can i get csrf token in html meta tags using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

How can i get csrf token in html meta tags using spring boot?

> I already done the CSRF token in SPRING by using xml configuration

Currently my project is in SPRING BOOT. I tried a lot but no luck.

I have an html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Boot project</title>
        <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="LoginPanel">
            <form role="form" action="LoginAuth">
                <input value="sample" type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" data-parsley-type="alphanum" placeholder="Username" required/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-block Signin btn btn-labeled1 btn-warning">
                    Sign in
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var Form = $(".LoginPanel").find("form");
            $(".LoginPanel").find("button.Signin").click(function(Event)
            {       
                Event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "LoginAuth",
                    data: Form.serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function (xhr,settings)
                    {
                        var CSRFToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");console.log(CSRFToken);
                        var CSRFHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");console.log(CSRFHeader);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(CSRFHeader, CSRFToken);
                    },
                    success: function(ResponseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        console.log(ResponseData);alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My security config is

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf();
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
security.basic.enabled=false
security.enable-csrf=true
```

After run the project, still i get the the null token & header name

I expected from the page source like this

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="7d789af1-996f-4241-ab70-2421da47bb09"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-XSRF-TOKEN"/>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: check your http response first, if there is a csrf token exists

Answer (score 3):

You're not indicating that the `content` attribute is dynamic in any way, so it's not getting processed. You didn't specify what template engine you're using, but this *looks* like Thymeleaf, so here's what your tag should look like:

```
<meta name="_csrf" data-th-content="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Comment: Currently i am not using any template engine. Is template engine must?

Comment: @user2214646 Yes, since you have to have *something* that's going to fill in those placeholders in the HTML. If you make this change and add the Thymeleaf starter, it should Just Work.

Comment: Don't know why this answer was downvoted. It's a valid answer.
Wondering if OP downvoted by mistake instead of accepting the answer.